# NSMutableArray Acts Strangely When Adding New Object

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I am programming a bug identifier application and am storing the description of my bugs in an array that will be stored to a Parse database. A single view controller passes 10 or so bugs to the viewer. However, when a user pressed the submit button, the array acts very strangely.

```
- (IBAction)addOrSubmitPressed:(id)sender {
if ([_bugCountLabel.text integerValue] > totalBugs) {
    pickerStatus = New;
    [self showPickerFor:pickerStatus];

} else if ([_bugCountLabel.text integerValue] == totalBugs) {
    // Save values to the current identity
    SFBugIdentity *identity = [cardData objectAtIndex:index];
    identity.stringsOfBugs = tableViewCells;
    identity.totalBugs = totalBugs;
    [cardData replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:identity];
    NSLog(@"Added a card with %li total bugs, %lu strings.", (long)identity.totalBugs, (unsigned long)identity.stringsOfBugs.count);
    [bugStrings addObject:identity.stringsOfBugs];
    NSLog(@"%@", identity.stringsOfBugs);
    NSLog(@"%@", bugStrings);

    // Reset all values (a bit sloppy atm...)
    [tableViewCells removeAllObjects];
    totalBugs = 0;
    [_tableView reloadData];

    // Load the next item in the array, if there is one. Otherwise shoot up to Parse and dismiss this view controller
    index++;
```

Great. So at first, the log will read out:

```
2015-09-15 17:57:09.459 PestCap[43286:455596] (
    "1 x Gnat"
)
2015-09-15 17:57:09.460 PestCap[43286:455596] (
        (
        "1 x Gnat"
    )
)
```

But then, when I add another object, this happens:

```
2015-09-15 18:03:56.148 PestCap[43286:455596] Added a card with 2 total 

bugs, 2 strings.
2015-09-15 18:03:56.148 PestCap[43286:455596] (
    "1 x Gnat",
    "1 x House Fly"
)
2015-09-15 18:03:56.148 PestCap[43286:455596] (
        (
        "1 x Gnat",
        "1 x House Fly"
    ),
        (
        "1 x Gnat",
        "1 x House Fly"
    )
)
```

What is going on? bugStrings is inside of the @implementation, allocated in ViewDidLoad, and is ONLY called when I add objects to it (besides when I access the objects for storing to Parse, but that code is not being executed at this point).

Edit: Other information: tableViewCells is an NSMutableArray of NSStrings that I use as a data source for the table on the view controller. totalBugs is a global variable that gets reset whenever a card is submitted.

Comment: I don't really understand your question, but I think you are confused as to why both elements of the array have the same value? This is because arrays store references to objects, not values of those objects.  So when you put `bugStrings` in the first element of the array and the second element and modify `bugStrings` then both elements are referring to the same (updated) string object, so they show the same valies

Comment: What @Paulw said.  The `bugStrings` array contains two instances of the `stringsOfBugs` array.  You could try `[bugStrings addObject:identity.stringsOfBugs.lastObject]`, but I suppose you could then just use `copy`.

Comment: There are plenty of ambiguity and lack of clarity in the question. Some important pieces are missing like where is this `index` coming from. If it is a local variable then it would get reset with each time tap on Submit button. Request you to please elaborate little more for us to help you :).